# What do I need to do to add a new QGIS project to qgis-web-client?

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

for weeks I'm trying to get QGIS Server with qgis-web-client to work but I'm totally stuck. System is Debian Squeeze. In principle, I get QGIS Server and the qgis-web-client up and running: it's possible to have a look at the example projects "Hello World" and "Natural Earth"; they're loaded in qgis-web-client just fine. The "only" problem I can't get rid of is the fact, that I don't know what to do to have a look at my own projects.

One thing to mention: Actually, we're running our services with NGINX. So I set it up as a proxy for Apache, which ist listening on port 8008.

I've been looking on the internet for a step by step procedure which explains whicht settings I have to set up that my own projects are also working in the web client. As you can see on [this website](http://assip.project.tuwien.ac.at/qgiswebclient.html?map=/srv/www/assip/htdocs/apache/qgis-web-client/projects/helloworld.qgs) the client is able to render the map and also an extra layer I took from http://www.diva-gis.org .

But saving another project in QGIS (named indonesia_1.qgs) including exactly the same layer and trying to show it in qgis-web-client leads to an [empty map](http://assip.project.tuwien.ac.at/qgiswebclient.html?map=/srv/www/assip/htdocs/apache/qgis-web-client/projects/indonesia_1.qgs).

Any help is really appreciated. I've read the README files and tutorials in the Wiki but I cannot solve this issue alone.

Thanks a lot for your help. I guess I'm just doing a tiny mistake here -- somewhere.

Niklaas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server works just fine. Use the search field in the upper right corner to search for Indonesia and you will be zoomed there.

The only thing that seems to be misconfigured is the default location and/or zoom level.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I also just found the problem. Damn! :) Great software, btw. I still need to get more comfortable with it so I know how to change the default location. But I'm really looking forward to work with it.

Comment: @niklaas Happy to help. Please upvote helpful answers and accept answers that solve your problem by clicking the tick mark on the left.

Comment: I will upvote your answer as soon as I can; unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet.